# How to find script tag exists inside a <p> tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am getting script tag inside a html `<p>` tags.

Example:

```
<p>
   <script>
     function essb_window1149322389(oUrl, oService) {
       essb_window_stat(oUrl, oService, 55311);  
     };
   </script>
</p>
```

Is their any ways to find , If `<script>` tag is exists inside `<p>` tag using jquery.

Comment: What is the objective of this?  Once the script has been parsed (which it already will be by the time you can run code that detects it), it does not matter where it's location was.  In fact, you could even remove the script tag DOM object and it would not change what happens in the page one bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using jQuery [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('p').find('script').length
```

Note, this will search direct and nested children. If you only want direct script children, use [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) as there will be a small performance gain.

```
$('p').children('script').length
//equivalent to $('p script').length
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bp7ox6e3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) or [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), using length with selector tells if element exists. If length is greater than 0 then script tag exists.

```
if($('p script').length)
{
     //exists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular selector (parent/child by node type) should work:

```
if ($("p script").length) ...
```